# Regex to find if all the characters in a word are the same specific character

Tags: regex

I have a set of words coming in one by one like aa, @#, ???, ~~~, ?~ etc

I need a regex to find if any of these words is containing only ? or only ~.
Of the above input examples, ??? and ~~~ should match but not the others.

I tried `^[\s?]*$` and `^[\s~]*$` separately and it works, I am trying to combine them.
`^[\s?||~]*$` doesn't work as it also recognizes ?~ as valid.

Any help?

Comment: Why do you want a Regex?. Surely a simpler approach is to do a replace and then check to see if the length is zero

Comment: @freeflow that sure is a good approach :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex, which looks for a string starting with a `~` or a `?`, and then asserts that every other character in the string is the same as the first one using a backreference (`\1`):

```
 ^([~?])\1+$
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/v3BvkW/3)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html?wlr=1) to achived your desired result.

If you want only `~` or `?` use

```
^([~?])\1+$
```

If you want any repetitive pattern, use

```
^(.)\1+$
```

**Explanation** `(.)` or `([~?])` capturing the first charactor.
Then, `\1+` checking the first charactor, one or more times (backreferencing)

Answer (score 0):

You want to match lines that both start and end with any number of either a tilde or questionmark. That would be `^\(~\|?\)*$`. The parentheses to make a group and the vertical bar to do the 'or' need to be backslash escaped.

Comment: I want to match a line that only contains tilde or only contain question mark - ??? or ~~~. not ?~, ?u? ~gg~ etc

Comment: Indeed, i see you edited the question to require an asterisk, which I've added.